# Multiple configurable attributes for products (that may not affect the price)

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

I have products that have two(-three) configurable attributes:

1. Size (3 possible options)
2. Style (3 possible options)
3. Colour (~20 possible options)

The price is only affected by the first two options, and **not** the colour. However, I have to show the style and colour options together like:

Style 1 
 - Red 
 - Blue

Style 2 
 - Red
 - Blue
etc..

So my question is, *is there a way to avoid creating 3*3*20 simple products*, and create only 9 which are the number of different prices for different configurable options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with configurable products. But if you choose to custom options, then yes. And the fact that you don't want to create the multiple variations would suggest to me that you don't need to track their inventory, in which case, custom options is the best solution for you anyway.

Comment: Thanks James. Although I will have to repeat the same price across colour options, it is quite better that creating multiple simple products.